# form validation error when destroying validator

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I have a form, within a modal, that uses [formValidation](http://formvalidation.io/). It builds itself using a common HTML form and then possibly extends with more fields in a JS function.

However in this particular case, I want to *remove* a field from the common HTML form, and remove it from form validation. I have taken 3 steps to do this

1. use jquery .remove() on the field
2. set the formvalidation field setting to `enabled : false`
3. Use formvalidation programmatically to disable the field

`$('#form').formValidation('enableFieldValidators', 'field', false)`

When I close my modal/form i call

`$('#form').formValidation('destroy', true)`

and I get the error

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined`

My guess is it is still looking for that field.

Do I have to forcefully remove the field property from the `validationOptions` object? I thought setting `enable` to `false` would be enough..